# On Duplicate Key update with combined values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm wondering what would be a good approach to tackle the following.

Visitors are allowed to vote once per topic (but they may change their vote). I have setup a simple table with the following values. Only VoteID is Unique/primary key. MemberID and Topic ID are foreign keys.

```
VoteID   MemberID   TopicID  Timestamp   ratingvalue
```

I read about the mysql on duplicate Key Update thing but that does not seem to help me I think, because what I'm looking for is to check if a member (id) has allready voted on a topic. If he did, update,  else insert (the ratingvalue and timestamp).

Before I'll implement a double query (1) to check if a user allready voted (2) to insert or either update. I thought I ask the community.

Any thoughts or suggestions on the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your situation is *exactly* what `on duplicate key update` is designed for.  You need to start with a unique index for the members and topics:

```
create unique index idx_votes_memberid_topicid on votes(memberid, topicid)
```

Then you do the insert as:

```
insert into votes(memberid, topicid, ratingvalue)
    select @memberid, @topicid, @ratingvalue
    on duplicate key update
        ratingvalue = values(ratingvalue),
        timestamp = now();
```

Note:  you can also set the timestamp to the current time or declare it to be automatically updated when the data changes.  For this, see the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Thx!  When you say: "you need to start with a unique index for the members and topics" do you mean add an extra column that *combines* the member and topic id? As suggested by Raul in the comment below?

Comment: I found out that you create a unique index on two columns. Thx your suggestion is very helpful and prevents to have another column with that unique combination

Comment: @rinserepeat . . . As a note:  I much prefer the auto-incremented primary key with an explicit `unique` index to a composite primary key.  In other words, I prefer your original table layout.

Comment: Thanks for your additional note!

Answer (score 1):

If I had a table were a member can vote only once in a topic, I would consider to make memberID+topicID as the primary key of the table. You'll be sure only one vote for a member and as a primary key, it will be faster to search.

There are many databases and each has its unique functions, maybe your database has one function to do it, like the "IF NOT EXISTS" in sql server or "MERGE" in Oracle.
Personally, It works better for me first to solve the problem and then try to do it faster.

Comment: Thanks for your smart suggestion. I assume you would combine them with a nonnumeric delimeter to prevent numbers overlapping like 22t18. Where T indicates the start of the topic id?

Comment: Yes, that would work. About your concern about querying before deciding, I guess you work on PHP, I use java but I'm sure you have similar funcionality in PHP: What I did in one project was to run an update, the function in java that updates returns an integer with the number of rows affected, if the result is 0, I know the record does not exist and then I run an Insert.  
You still need to run 2 queries but at least your code will only need to handle an update+insert instead of a select count(*) followed by an update or an insert.

Comment: nice one thanks for your suggestion! ANd yes im working on a "default" lamp stack :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to understand if the user has already voted for a particular topic, what exactly will be updated? I thought he would be just told that he had already voted for the topic and not allowed to vote anymore?

In any case, I would prefer to check it in the application rather than relying on the database constraints for performance reasons.

Comment: The rating value and the timestamp as stated in the text, someone can change its mind and vote 10 instead of 9

Comment: Oh,alright! if performance is your concern (and it should be), you can run a few tests for your database for the two cases to benchmark.